# Off-topic requests for assistance

Tags: discussion, support

Came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453876/searchable-name-for-equation-evaluating-caching-smart-updating-lib) in the Close Votes queue. Everything considered, I've seen countless questions like this closed as Off-Topic. However,

- OP clearly knows SO rules (13,7K rep)
- Question is very concise, well-worded and someone on SO probably knows the answer (despite the lack of answers).

So, the question is, should we *always* close topics as such? To me, this is one of the rare questions that could probably hang around.

That said, something like [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) could be a better arena for this question (but I don't subscribe to that one personally).

Assistance appreciated on this one.

Comment: rep shouldn't  matter in how to moderate a post.

Comment: I'm not sure about the "OP clearly knows SO rules" argument when they post a "I'm looking for a library" - question.

Comment: Well, the OP knows the rules well enough to formulate the question so you doubt it is an off topic resource request.  In general a problem, after 9 years many questioners know the tricks, makes picking a close-vote reason difficult.

Comment: @HansPassant: If picking a close reason is difficult, shouldn't a question not be closed (or even be reopened)?

Comment: Lots of questions get heavily downvoted without ever getting a single close vote.  The dialog is just not a very suitable tool to address such questions, you can't vote "not good enough to belong here".  So a DV is all you got.  Hopefully they don't get an answer, but it is not a good guarantee and they often do, even months after being posted.  The Roomba helps a lot.  Well, helps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, OP's goal is to find a library - by himself. He doesn't ask us to provide one. He asks us to identify the underlying paradigm, concept or idiom of what he is planning to achieve. He asks for a "searchable name".

> **Searchable name** for 'equation evaluating, caching, smart updating' lib
>
> I'm looking for a library but I'm not sure what to search for because
>   I'm not sure what to call the task I want to do (in such a way that
>   it's searchable).

I think that such questions are a good fit for SO. We often encounter specific instances of problems which can be solved by a solution targeting an entire class of those problems. Identifying and naming = classifying a problem is the first step to finding a solution.

OP might have a little bit more clear on that though by avoiding the mention of the trigger word 'library'.

Comment: That was my thought. It seemed that the question is more about seeking the right term to do his own search with.